# Change port number in JBoss EAP 6.0.1

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, port

Can anyone tell me where can I find the default port number for JBoss EAP 6.0.1 and how I can change it? If there is a file I can edit, I would much prefer that than change it in Eclipse or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are talking about the port for HTTP which defaults to 8080. You can change it in the file `JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`.

Comment: I just did a search on my JBoss directory for a server.xml and there weren't any results.

Comment: Pleas try `JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`

Comment: I found it but I see a lot of port numbers. Which one would I change if I wanted to test a web service on a browser?

Comment: You want to change the HTTP port. Just search the file for `8080` or `HTTP` and change the number to whatever you like.

Comment: Have a look at [JBoss EAP Socket Binding Groups](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/sect-Socket_Binding_Groups.html)

Answer (score 3):

I know you mentioned you'd rather not use Eclipse, but in case you or anybody else may want to try, here's a simple alternative method to configure it through Eclipse:

1. Click on the 'Server' View
2. Expand the instance of JBoss you wish to run on (e.g. JBoss AS 7.1)
3. Expand XML Configuration
4. Expand Ports
5. Right click on JBoss Web
6. Select 'Change Value', and change the port number (e.g. 8082)

[image: jboss eclipse change port number]

After that you can simply right click on your project, select 'Run As', then 'Run on Server' (choose the Server you just configured), click 'Next' or 'Finish', and your project should open in a new browser on that port (i.e. localhost:8082/html5demo/)